# Multiply all values in a pandas df by max value within group

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to return the max value within a pandas `df` for each specific group. I then want to use this max value to multiply separate values and return in a separate column.

For example, using the `df` below, the max value for each group in `Item` is:

```
X = 5
Y = 2
```

I want to use these values to multiply all other values as a separate column. 
import pandas as pd

```
d = ({
    'Item' : ['X','X','X','Y','Y','Y','Y'],                 
    'Count' : [0,2,5,3,1,2,1],                                      
    })

df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
```

This is my attempt:

```
df['Mult_max'] = df.groupby('Item').apply(lambda x: x['Count'].max() * x['Count'])
```

Intended Output:

```
  Group  Value  Mult_max
0     X      0         0
1     X      2        10
2     X      5        25
3     Y      3         9
4     Y      1         3
5     Y      2         6
6     Y      1         3
```

Comment: `df.groupby('Item')['Count'].apply(lambda x: x.max() * x)` would work too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for Series with same size like original `DataFrame` filled by max values:

```
df['Mult_max'] = df.groupby('Item')['Count'].transform('max') * df['Count']
print (df)
  Item  Count  Mult_max
0    X      0         0
1    X      2        10
2    X      5        25
3    Y      3         9
4    Y      1         3
5    Y      2         6
6    Y      1         3
```

Comment: That was quick @jezrael. Thanks